# Corona / Lua Function scope

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Corona. I'm not sure how to solve this.

In main I am creating 2 local objects, player and enemy.

Player has a function called takeDamage.

When I try to call player.takeDamage from within enemy, it can't see the function.

I presume it's because main owns both objects and they don't know about each other.

How can I have Enemy call that function so that it can deal damage to Player?

main.lua contains:

```
-- Create player character
local player = require("player");
player = player.new();

-- Create enemy character
local enemy = require("enemy");
enemy = enemy.new();
```

I think I could make player global, but from what I know, that would not be a best practice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `player:takeDamage` ?  the semicolon denotes it as an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

If it is safe to assume that there will be only one "player" instance, you *can* make it global. Otherwise, you would have to do something along these lines:

```
-- main.lua
local player = require 'player'.new()
local enemy = require 'enemy'.new()
enemy:setPlayer(player)

-- enemy.lua
...
function enemy:setPlayer(player)
  self.player = player
end
```

And later use `self.player` in the enemy code to reference the player. Note that this will consume memory, because the player reference will be copied to every enemy instance.

One side note, I do not consider it good to call a module and an instance the same, i.e. `player`. It will become unclear later if you mean the module, or the instance. A safe way would be to call the modules as `Player` and `Enemy`, and the code will look like this:

```
Player = require 'Player'
local player = Player.new()
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. There is only one player in this game. Everything else will either be a static object that can be interacted with, or an enemy. I see what you're doing here, giving the enemy a reference to the player. Would you say that is better than making the player global?   Thanks for clarifying the naming convention. I agree that the names should at least be capped differently for clarity.

Comment: I personally would design `player` using a global variable. One reason is that it will be available everywhere, and you do not have to design sophisticated schemes like the one I wrote. Another reason is memory - you only have one reference to the player, instead of N (number of enemies). One final approach is to have a `gameState` global, which will contain the player and other necessary game state.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the enemies might also need to interact with each other, so I'm not sure if the global option would be good then. We don't want all the entities to be global, do we?

Comment: Of course not :) But then again, you could save all enemies in a global state, such as `gameState.enemies = {}`. Then you can traverse it for each enemies in this fashion: `function Enemy:checkCollision() for _,e in ipairs(gameState.enemies) do if e ~= self then --[[ your processing here ]] end end`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you don't want the player referencing the enemy directly or the enemy referencing the player. Instead, you could poll each participant in a game loop and update the game state based on the result.

```
local player = make_player()
local enemy = make_enemy()

--game loop - in a real game this isn't a busy while
while true do

    local move = player.move()
    local result = validate_move(move)
    if result.is_valid then 
        update_position(player, result) 
    end

    move = enemy.move()
    result = validate_move(move)
    if result.is_valid then 
        update_position(enemy, result) 
    end

    local attack = player.attack()
    local attack_result = validate_attack(attack)
    if attack_result.hit then 
        update_health(enemy, attack_result) 
    end

    -- more game logic here

    render(player)
    render(enemy)
end
```

In a real game, state change would be driven by [events](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/application-programming-guide-event-handling) - touch events, [drawing events](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/application-programming-guide-graphics-and-drawing#Drawing_Cycle), etc. My busy loop (`while true do`) illustrates the general idea.

You'll also have to use your imagination for missing implementation.

There are many ways to model a game. I'm not suggesting this is the best. It does, however, show one way of decoupling interacting elements.

Comment: Thanks for replying Corbin. Is the model you show here more for turn based games, or would it apply to any? I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for, but I'll think about it and see if I can figure how it would fit what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Kenny - It works for turn or real-time games. Replace my `while` loop with an event - UI actions (turn or real-time) or a frame event (real-time only). The key characteristic is a controller/broker/manager that coordinates actions between elements that can interact versus linking those elements with direct references. Keeping them detached can make it easier to reason about their actions and responsibilities.